# Does the Canon Powershot A series have an orientation sensor?

Tags: canon

Recently bought a Canon Powershot A490 - which is a well priced camera that accepts AA batteries, with the familiar Canon UI which I like.

Looking to pick up another Canon A series camera, but I'd like to confirm if any have an orientation sensor to tag photos so that they auto-rotate when viewing both on the camera and on most computers.

It's difficult to get confirmation on which models include this feature - I know the A490 doesn't but I'm wondering if the A480 or the A495 do.  Canon's website (and camera comparison tool) does not seem to provide this information.

Comment: All of a sudden, my old A20 feels **very** old... (which I think did do orientation, by the way)

Answer (score 4):

You can find out my checking the exif data for pictures taken with the model in question.

I looked on flickr for a sample image and found [one taken with an A495](http://www.flickr.com/photos/cameralabs/4524795412/meta/in/photostream) that does have the orientation marked.

This isn't a guarantee, as the data could be added later, but it certainly does make me believe that the camera does have an orientation sensor.

Comment: Every camera I've used which lacks the sensor has some menu function where you can go through and manually change the rotation information. (My knowledge here covers Pentax, Fujifilm, and Olympus, but I'm sure others do it as well.) So I wouldn't count on that.

Answer (score 2):

I had a Canon A540 and it *did* have an orientation sensor... images were oriented correctly both on the camera's display and on my computer.